# How to change workspace within Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I have been running eclipse for a few months on my laptop using a certain workspace, however I know have started developing with android and downloaded the ADT bundle from:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

This bundle also contains eclipse, so now i have two versions of eclipse on my laptop. I would like to merge the two so that I only need to use one, and that I am always working off the one workspace

Comment: In hindsight, would it be possible to use the ADT bundle with eclipse to develop with android and use my other version of eclipse to develop Java programs?

Comment: You can create two separate workspaces, you don't need two versions of eclipse to keep them separate though, unless you want two workspaces open at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto  File --> Import, then select Existing Projects into Workspace.
select  root directory of existing workspace.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to merge the two, you can erase the older version if you wish. You can use your workspace in either version of Eclipse but not at the same time.

Good luck.